# Does MVC Razor generate HTML for the template in the view on client side or server side?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to understand where the Razor View Engine actually generates the HTML from the templates that we create in the view. For example see the following code snippet,

```
<ul id="products" >

<% foreach(var p in products) { %>

  <li><%=p.Name%> ($<%=p.Price%>)</li>
<% } %>

</ul>
```

I wanted to understand if the processing to generate the resultant html will be done in the browser or the web server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to understand where the Razor View Engine actually generates
>   the HTML from the templates that we create in the view

It happens on the web server. Once the HTML is fully created on the web server, this HTML is sent to the client browser.

Answer (score 2):

**On the web server!**

The browser (thus on client side) can only process Javascript.
Razor is an engine such as aspx, Php and so on that helps in dynamically generate html from templated views.

Answer (score 2):

**Obviously Razor View Engine will Render on Web Server** like any dynamic web programming language such as PHP , etc... . Consider that if it being rendered by browser or any place except web server, **We will have security issue** by inspecting our pages and finally a nonsuccessive web application.

> The server port (8080(http) or 8443(https)) only sends rendered (html) pages with its relevants
>   like *.js and *.css files.

**Edit:**

**If you ignore correct syntax of Razor View Engine, It will be appeared at page with @ derivative.**

**You can also write scripts inside views and use Razor Syntax inside them and they will be rendered correctly as you want.**

Comment: I actually asked the question because technically it is possible for the framework to transform the c# code to javascript. I was interested to know if it is using that capability or just sending ASP style html. Thanks.

Comment: Razor engine intelligently parse the C# and HTML code and this can happen only on the server side.